# Default owner of new files and directories?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod, mkdir

How does one configure an Ubuntu 10.10 system to behave like this:

1. User creates a new directory or file.
2. User is the default owner of this file.
3. The file's (or directory's) permissions default to where the owner has RWX, and everyone else has read-only permissions.

Comment: did you want to enforce this for all users, or just a single user?

Answer (score 9):

Items #1 and #2 are how Ubuntu works already.

To achieve #3 you need to set the umask ([wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)) to 0022